# what is the procedure to develop ReactJS with Bootstrap hybrid app

Tags: android, ios, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

What is the procedure to develop ReactJS with Bootstrap hybrid app.
I am new to the mobile development, i have good experience in Web Applications development with jQuery, Bootstrap etc.I have started learning ReactJS 
Now,

```
i like to know how to develop Hybrid app with ReactJS. like 
- what are the tools to develop (i am using IntelliJ IDE)
- Need to learn additional technologies ?
- how to test ?
- how to integrate with Android or iOS ? etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

my suggestions:

Check out cordova for the basic framework to build hybrid apps.
Running Ract Applications inside cordova works pretty well actually.

The IDE shouldnt matter too much. You will end up writing most of your stuff in javascript. Therefore an IDE that can support different ECMAScript versions is favorable.
In rare cases u will end up building plugins for cordova which is the only time you will have contact with other languages.

If you are looking for a test framework its also a question of taste.
Since React comes with its own Test Library which can basicly be run out of every Framework you want. I like using Jasmine a lot so.

This answer should give you enough starting points to look for.
For deeper insights ... Google is your friend ^^

hope it helps